# Adding non-required fields to form

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement

I am trying to add non-required fields but not sure how to add multiple strings. Adding one is fine but it stops working when I add multiple. Can anyone point out what I may be missing? Below is the code;

```
jQuery( '#appointment-popup' ).on( 'click', 'input.submit-appointment', function() {

    values = {
        'name' : '',
        'phone' : '',
        'email' : '',
        'appointment-date' : '',
        'approximate-time' : '',
        'place' : '',
        'additional-notes' : '',
        'solutions' : ''
    };        


    areErrors = false;
    jQuery.each( values, function( key, value ) {

        currentElement = jQuery( '#appointment-form-in-popup form *[name='+ key +']' );
        values[key] = currentElement.val();
        if( key != 'additional-notes' ) { // put here unrequired fields

            if( values[key] != false ) { currentElement.removeClass( 'error' ); }
            else {
                currentElement.addClass( 'error' );
                areErrors = true;   
            }
        }

    });

    if( areErrors == false ) {

        // your action here, for example sending an email...
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: path_to_template +'/_assets/submit.php',
            data: { 'submit': 'appointment-form', 'data': values, 'email': appointment_contact },
            type: 'post',
            success: function( output ) {

                // animation after your action
                jQuery.appointmentFormAnimation();
            }
        });
    }

});    
jQuery.appointmentFormAnimation = function() {

    formHeight = jQuery( '.appointment-popup-content' ).height();
    jQuery( '.appointment-popup-content' ).css({ 'minHeight' : formHeight });

    jQuery( '#appointment-form-in-popup form' ).fadeOut( 300 );
    setTimeout( function() {

        jQuery( '#appointment-form-in-popup .thanks' ).fadeIn( 300 );

    }, 400 );      
}
```

Comment: why not just remove the non-required fields from the values ?

Comment: Just a heads-up, if someone to decides to turn off JavaScript, or edit the HTML (using Firebug for example) they would still be able to leave required fields empty. You're best of doing this server side (E.G. PHP for checking values).